# Mathematica can't plot numerically integrated function

Tags: plotting, calculus-and-analysis, numerical-integration

I have this function with variable "x" and parameters "H, M, a. s," which for some reason is impossible to integrate in Mathematica so i tried to integrate with "NIntegrate" i got the anwser numerically but i can't plot it now.Please help
Here's the function.

```
V = (-a Sqrt[(1 + 2 x) + 
 H^2/a ((3 Subscript[V, 0])/(2 (1 + 2 x)^2) - Subscript[V, 10]/(
    2 (1 + 2 x)))] + (a - 1) Sqrt[(1 + 2 x) + 
 H^2/a ((3 Subscript[V, 0])/(2 s^3 (1 - (2 x)/s)^2) - Subscript[V,
     10]/(2 s^2 (1 - (2 x)/s)))] + 1/Sqrt[1 - (2 x)/M^2])
```

Regards.

Comment: The definition of `V` is wrong, error message `$RecursionLimit::reclim2: Recursion depth of 1024 exceeded during evaluation of 1/Sqrt[1-(2 x)/M^2].` is due to `Subscript[V, 10]`.For Mathematica it's the same variable as `V`.

Comment: I avoid `Subscript`, except in output-formatting, so I don't have to worry about the trouble it can cause.  I probably understand the issues well enough to avoid them, but why make more work for myself?  Ditto for using capital-letter variables. See https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/18395/4999