# Can't plot a function after NIntegration

Tags: plotting, calculus-and-analysis

I have a function which cannot be integrated on Mathematica. So i integrated it with NIntegrate. Now i want to plot my funtion after integration. But how can i plot it after numerical integration.

```
Sqrt[1 + 2 x + ( H^2 (-((-a Sqrt[1 + 2 x] + 1/Sqrt[
  1 - (2 x)/M^2] + (-1 + a) Sqrt[1 - (2 x)/s])/(
 2 s^2 (1 - (2 x)/s))) + (
3 (1/3 a (1 - (1 + 2 x)^(3/2)) + M^2 (1 - Sqrt[1 - (2 x)/M^2]) + 
   1/3 (-1 + a) s (1 - (1 - (2 x)/s)^(3/2))))/(
2 s^3 (1 - (2 x)/s)^2)))/a]
```

Comment: Could you please add parameter values?  Have you tried `Plot`?  What went wrong?

Comment: BTW, welcome to Mathematica.SE, Naveed! I suggest the following: 
1) Take the [tour](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) and check the [faqs](http://goo.gl/kQNRaS).   
2) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by clicking the gray triangles, because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by clicking the checkmark sign! 
3) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise.

Comment: Is it the same question [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/219854/mathematica-cant-plot-numerically-integrated-function)? Please, consider adding details to one question and not creating multiples.